# Why would a faucet still leak with a new cartridge installed?

Tags: faucet, bathroom-fixtures

I've replaced 3 faucet cartridges in my house.  The 2 oldest repairs/replacements (replaced about 1.5 yrs ago) are still good.  The most recent one is about 4 months old but it has started leaking again.

When I went to get the replacement cartridges, I brought the bad one to the store to match up so it should be the correct one.

Is there anything I should look at to fix it to stop it from leaking again?  I doubt I did anything wrong since the other two are still ok, although it's not outside the realm of possibility that I made a mistake.

I plan to replace the rubber seats (the rubber thing sitting on top of the spring) first before I buy a new cartridge to try out but in case both of these steps don't work, what should I do since logically, replacing the cartridge should fix it?

Comment: Look for foreign material or burs on the machined surface inside the old faucet.  There could be a sharp edge or some trash that wears on the cartridge.

Comment: I was also thinking of scratches these tear up the seals, I have seen damage caused from scale/rust or small gravel in the past that scored the valve body so new seals only lasted a few months.

Comment: @EdBeal thanks for your reply.  I didn't see any scale or rust but part of the top of the seal was worn out a little.  I tried twisting the cartridge a little so the bottom doesn't rub/cut into the seal.  We'll see how long it lasts.

Comment: @JPhi1618 and Ed Beal, so if we clean up these burs on the inside of the faucet housing will this prevent the cartride from leaking?

Comment: @Platypus, if there is some _extra_ material that you can clean out and you are not left with a scratch or gouge in the faucet then it should stop a new cartridge from getting scratched and leak.  If the housing has a scratch, you can clean it up, but if its too deep, it may leak anyway.  Main thing is to make sure you have smooth surfaces with no debris in the housing.